# Как сделать прерывистую вибрацию на Андроиде в Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-berlin

Как сделать вибрацию, которая будет такой же, как и при входящем звонке, то есть не постоянная, а прерывистая?

Сейчас включаю вибро так:

```
VibratorObj := SharedActivity.getSystemService(TJActivity.JavaClass.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  Vibrator := TJVibrator.Wrap((VibratorObj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  Vibrator.vibrate(10);
```

Answer (score 4):

В Android API, у класса Vibrator есть метод

```
vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)
```

В Делфи, этот метод выглядит так

```
vibrate(pattern: TJavaArray<Int64>; repeat_: Integer);
```

на вход принимает два параметра:

- Массив "pattern" значений в миллисекундах. Чередование идёт в таком порядке [pause, vibrate, pause, ... , vibrate, pause]
- Флаг повтора "repeat_", "-1" значит не повторять, либо указывается индекс из массива "pattern", с этого индекса начнётся повторение.

Также вы можете почитать статью [Используем вибрацию на Android устройствах](http://delphifmandroid.blogspot.ru/2014/01/android.html)

Или воспользоваться классом с гитхаба: [https://github.com/AndrewEfimov/Android-API/tree/master/Vibrator](http://github.com/AndrewEfimov/Android-API/tree/master/Vibrator)

Есть ещё полезный форум по FMX, там также есть ответ http://fire-monkey.ru/

**Update**: Как создать массив "TJavaArray" (Требуется подключить юнит "Androidapi.JNIBridge")

```
function IntArrayToJArray(const OrigArray: array of Integer): TJavaArray<Int64>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := TJavaArray<Int64>.Create(Length(OrigArray));
  for i := Low(OrigArray) to High(OrigArray) do
    Result.Items[i] := OrigArray[i];
end;
```

или так

```
function TForm2.CreateJavaLongArray(const ASource: TArray<string>): TJavaArray<Int64>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := TJavaArray<Int64>.Create(Length(ASource));
  for i := Low(ASource) to High(ASource) do
    Result.Items[i] := ASource[i].ToInt64;
end;
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо в ответ включить, как создать и инициализировать TJavaArray для передачи его в метод Vibrate

Comment: Добавил примеры кода

Answer (score 2):

Подробнее

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
 Vibrator:JVibrator;
 Pattern:TJavaArray<Int64>;
begin
 Vibrator:=TJVibrator.Wrap((SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  If NOT Vibrator.hasVibrator Then Exit;
(*
 Шаблон Vibrate 0, 100, 1000, 250, 1000
 0 = старт без задержки
 100 - вибрация 100ms
 1000 - пазуа 1000ms
 250 - вибрация 250ms
 1000 - пауза 1000ms
*)
 Pattern:=TJavaArray<Int64>.Create(5); // длина шаблона
 Pattern.Items[0]:=100;
 Pattern.Items[1]:=1000;
 Pattern.Items[2]:=100;
 Pattern.Items[3]:=1500;
 Pattern.Items[4]:=100;
 Vibrator.vibrate(Pattern, -1); // второй параметр: 1 = повторить шаблон один раз, -1 = провибрировать один раз

end;
```